# Async function returning before await is complete

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have two questions from the following example:

Why is does x log before y?
Why is x a Promise?

I'm expecting `bar` to wait for `foo` to resolve with the value `'Hello'` before it logs and then returns it.

```
let foo = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('Hello');
        }, 2000);
    })
}

let bar = async () => {
    let y = await foo();
    console.log(y);
    return y;
}

let x = bar();

console.log(x);
```

What I'm expecting to see is

```
'Hello' // console.log(y)
'Hello' // console.log(x)
```

What I'm getting is

```
 Promise {<pending>}  // console.log(x)
 'Hello'              // console.log(y)
```

Shouldn't `bar` wait for `foo` to resolve before returning `y`?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `bar()` is an `async` function but you're not calling it with `await`.

Comment: according to documentation `async` function returns `Promise` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the documentation about `async function`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

And `Promise` object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

It is stated that an `async function` returns a `Promise` object which is in a `pending` state until it is resolved.

---

Now let's look at your code:

You assign to `x` the return value of `bar()`, which is a `Promise`, since there is no `await` keyword to stop the execution (And you can not add one, because you are outside of an `async function`) this promise is logged as pending because the `async function bar()` has not yet returned.

Meanwhile, in the `async function bar()` you assign to `y` the return value of the `async function foo()` which is also a `Promise`, but this time you make it await for the result. After 2 seconds of waiting time, the promise is fulfiled and `y` is logged with the parameter of the `resolve()` method, which is `Hello`.

Thus the behaviour you witness is the expected one.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation! It's amazing how i miss the simple things for the docs. This, combined with @FrankModica's answer set me straight.

Answer (score 7):

You need to `await` the function:

```
let example = async () => {
    let foo = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve('Hello');
            }, 2000);
        })
    }

    let bar = async () => {
        let y = await foo();
        console.log(y);
        return y;
    }

    let x = await bar();

    console.log(x);
}

example();
```

Comment: This will give error of `await is only valid in async function`

Comment: I guess the chrome console allows it to execute without being wrapped (Firefox did give an error). I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `await` before calling `bar()` but, actually, you can use `await` just when you wrapped it by a `async` function like below:

```
async function Func() {

  let foo = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('Hello');
      }, 2000);
    })
  }

  let bar = async () => {
    let y = await foo();
    console.log(y);
    return y;
  }

  let x = await bar();

  console.log(x);

}
```

When you execute the `Func();` your expectation will fire.